# json encode format parse error by verifying online formatter

Tags: php, json

In PHP after coverting array with json_encode it outputs object as parse error. When I checked this object with online json formatter tools then it is showing errors. If I skipped the json validation it is displaying the json object. I tried with some formats to fix errors but these are not working and still showing errors in json formatter online tools. please anyone can get me to fix this format issue.

1. json_encode($arrayorobj,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
2. json_encode($arrayorobj,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

```json
     {"company":"test","phonenumber":"+27 51 405 1705","company_json":[{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test Home","htmlTitle":"test Home","link":"http://www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"The test B.U.I.L.D Programme aims to turn construction into a high-performance \nindustry and to unlock infrastructure potential to contribute better to national goals\n.","htmlSnippet":"The test B.U.I.L.D Programme aims to turn construction into a high-performance
    \nindustry and to unlock infrastructure potential to contribute better to national goals
    \n.","cacheId":"qSqnPGhJsdwJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Register of cts","htmlTitle":"Register of cts","link":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"Records 1 - 20 of 5000 ... ... for iinction: The word \u201ciinction\u201d is defined as a penalty, punishment, \nsentence or fine imposed for contravening the test prescripts.","htmlSnippet":"Records 1 - 20 of 5000 ... ... for iinction: The word \u201ciinction\u201d is defined as a penalty, punishment,
    \nsentence or fine imposed for contravening the test prescripts.","cacheId":"azgQHDrEtekJ","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Online Registration","htmlTitle":"Online Registration","link":"http://www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"Enter the grade(s) that you are applying for;; The total cost of your application will \nbe displayed on the screen;; Make a payment right here on the test website. Don\n\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"Enter the grade(s) that you are applying for;; The total cost of your application will
    \nbe displayed on the screen;; Make a payment right here on the test website. Don
    \n ...","cacheId":"KUara2nQlGwJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"ApplicationStatusSearch","htmlTitle":"ApplicationStatusSearch","link":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"test. skip to the main content area of this page. Home ... Copyright \u00a9 test 2011. \nAll rights reserved. Website technical enquires contact.","htmlSnippet":"test. skip to the main content area of this page. Home ... Copyright \u00a9 test 2011.
    \nAll rights reserved. Website technical enquires contact.","cacheId":"vvo5R3LhD-0J","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Tender Opportunities","htmlTitle":"Tender Opportunities","link":"http://www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"The test notifies cts registered on the Register of cts, ... is sent \nto cts that are registered in the specific test grade required for the tender\n\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"The test notifies cts registered on the Register of cts, ... is sent
    \nto cts that are registered in the specific test grade required for the tender
    \n ...","cacheId":"SSSt8kQXcHUJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test","htmlTitle":"test","link":"https://registers.test.org/","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"The Construction Registers Service comprises the Register of cts and \nthe Register of Projects which have been established in terms of the test Act\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"The Construction Registers Service comprises the Register of cts and
    \nthe Register of Projects which have been established in terms of the test Act ...","cacheId":"S3dK8ZPqEZEJ","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Construction Industry Development Board (test) - Overview","htmlTitle":"Construction Industry Development Board (test) - Overview","link":"https://testexxx.ii/units/view/210/construction-industry-development-board-test","displayLink":"testexxx.ii","snippet":"Overview. The mission of the Construction Industry Development Board (test) is \nto drive enhanced delivery management, capacity improvement and ct\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"Overview. The mission of the Construction Industry Development Board (test) is
    \nto drive enhanced delivery management, capacity improvement and ct ...","cacheId":"KJtVjHgjNkMJ","formattedUrl":"https://testexxx.ii/.../construction-industry-development-board -test","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://testexxx.ii/.../construction-industry-development-board -test","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsD9AYHLWsiy5QO22qDI7mY5B30GfhvPETXL6uR-rcOcSqIXAO_bmJpA","width":"239","height":"110"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://testexxx.ii/img/logos/thumb_construction_industry_development_board_%28test%29.png"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"register","htmlTitle":"register","link":"https://example/","displayLink":"example","snippet":"I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions. FORGOT PASSWORD? \nREGISTER. Contact Us. Terms and Conditions. \u00d7\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions. FORGOT PASSWORD?
    \nREGISTER. Contact Us. Terms and Conditions. \u00d7 ...","cacheId":"XH9EVI2lqvAJ","formattedUrl":"https://example/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://example/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZykxLL7kWOxz6cU9aGPCQmr9Q3bRkiCfGAu7PMscftwlTTpbu_fK_hsS","width":"351","height":"144"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0","apple-mobile-web-app-capable":"yes"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://example/Content/images/test_logo2.png"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Tenders - TNPA 879/test","htmlTitle":"Tenders - TNPA 879/test","link":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/Tenders/DispForm.aspx?ID=29&ContentTypeId=0x0100DC68709F4C4D2D458985558CAB051E88","displayLink":"www.example.net","snippet":"14 Apr 2021 ... This tender will be advertised directly on the test itender Publication Portal and \nexample TenderBulletins. If bidders intend to participate in this\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"14 Apr 2021 ... This tender will be advertised directly on the test itender Publication Portal and
    \nexample TenderBulletins. If bidders intend to participate in this ...","cacheId":"0p-vzg6lGmEJ","formattedUrl":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/.../DispForm.aspx?ID...","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/.../DispForm.aspx?ID...","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://datic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSceFg3sI_6y50Qs5S10N38i1lqocW45KPPXrNbEshgDB22nV4cf5G_70Q","width":"226","height":"223"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://www.example.net/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy ...","htmlTitle":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy ...","link":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","displayLink":"testing.org","snippet":"20 May 2020 ... Both test and CBE were asked to provide a detailed list of fraud and corruption \nin the sector. The Deputy Minister iiid the current legislation will\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"20 May 2020 ... Both test and CBE were asked to provide a detailed list of fraud and corruption
    \nin the sector. The Deputy Minister iiid the current legislation will ...","cacheId":"KXXySfmZHQ8J","formattedUrl":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3wXzgkuNa-GSn8xd1lHOjUmQgABu8JdW_75JwRxGK0rzrq2tUUWCT41dZ","width":"225","height":"225"}],"metatags":[{"og:image":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy Minister | testing","og:type":"website","twitter:site":"@testing_ii","viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1","twitter:description":"A meeting of the Public Works and Infrastructure committee held on 20 May 2020, lead by Ms N Ntobongwana (ANC)","og:title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy Minister | testing","twitter:creator":"@testing_ii","og:description":"A meeting of the Public Works and Infrastructure committee held on 20 May 2020, lead by Ms N Ntobongwana (ANC)","twitter:image":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png"}]}}],"phonenumber1_json":[{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Pharmacist in Bloemspruit, Bloemfontein, South Africa | Medical ...","htmlTitle":"Pharmacist in Bloemspruit, Bloemfontein, South Africa | Medical ...","link":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/1004A124/Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","displayLink":"www.testexample.com","snippet":"I Mr Cornelius Johannes (Johan) Combrink. Pharmacist 121 Dr Belcher Road, \nHeidedal, 9301. Tel: 051 405 1705Link. J Ms Conradie, Arlene. Pharmacist","htmlSnippet":"I Mr Cornelius Johannes (Johan) Combrink. Pharmacist 121 Dr Belcher Road,
    \nHeidedal, 9301. Tel: 051 405 1705Link. J Ms Conradie, Arlene. Pharmacist","cacheId":"kIpOwyhDiRMJ","formattedUrl":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/.../Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/.../Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","pagemap":{"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}]}}],"address":"rtret erteew"}
```

Comment: And _what_ errors do the online formatter tools show?

Comment: It's probably not the json_encode, but what you're doing with the json afterwards. There's a lot of newlines in there (both regular and the `\n`) that should not be there

Answer (score -1):

[image: This is an error in your JSON]

Valid:

[image]

Valid code:

```
{"company":"test","phonenumber":"+27 51 405 1705","company_json":[{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test Home","htmlTitle":"test Home","link":"http://www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"The test B.U.I.L.D Programme aims to turn construction into a high-performance \nindustry and to unlock infrastructure potential to contribute better to national goals\n.", "htmlSnippet":"The test B.U.I.L.D Programme aims to turn construction into a high-performance industry and to unlock infrastructure potential to contribute better to national goals.","cacheId":"qSqnPGhJsdwJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/Pages/Home.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Register of cts","htmlTitle":"Register of cts","link":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"Records 1 - 20 of 5000 ... ... for iinction: The word \u201ciinction\u201d is defined as a penalty, punishment, \nsentence or fine imposed for contravening the test prescripts.","htmlSnippet":"Records 1 - 20 of 5000 ... ... for iinction: The word \u201ciinction\u201d is defined as a penalty, punishment, sentence or fine imposed for contravening the test prescripts.","cacheId":"azgQHDrEtekJ","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ctSearch","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Online Registration","htmlTitle":"Online Registration","link":"http://www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"Enter the grade(s) that you are applying for;; The total cost of your application will \nbe displayed on the screen;; Make a payment right here on the test website. Don\n\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"Enter the grade(s) that you are applying for;; The total cost of your application will be displayed on the screen;; Make a payment right here on the test website. Don ...","cacheId":"KUara2nQlGwJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Online-Registration.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"ApplicationStatusSearch","htmlTitle":"ApplicationStatusSearch","link":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"test. skip to the main content area of this page. Home ... Copyright \u00a9 test 2011. \nAll rights reserved. Website technical enquires contact.","htmlSnippet":"test. skip to the main content area of this page. Home ... Copyright \u00a9 test 2011. All rights reserved. Website technical enquires contact.","cacheId":"vvo5R3LhD-0J","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/Publiccts/ApplicationStatusSearch","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Tender Opportunities","htmlTitle":"Tender Opportunities","link":"http://www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","displayLink":"www.test.org","snippet":"The test notifies cts registered on the Register of cts, ... is sent \nto cts that are registered in the specific test grade required for the tender\n\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"The test notifies cts registered on the Register of cts, ... is sent to cts that are registered in the specific test grade required for the tender ...","cacheId":"SSSt8kQXcHUJ","formattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","htmlFormattedUrl":"www.test.org/cts/Pages/Tender-Opportunities.aspx","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnM_CNfwOmKpX1G6A_nvgJtIzNXJqy4R3wBqFUaH1EZS_POcnAgqAtYyHd","width":"329","height":"153"}],"metatags":[{"miipplication-tilecolor":"#0072C6","miipplication-tileimage":"/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"http://www.test.org/SiteAssets/Logo%20large.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test","htmlTitle":"test","link":"https://registers.test.org/","displayLink":"registers.test.org","snippet":"The Construction Registers Service comprises the Register of cts and \nthe Register of Projects which have been established in terms of the test Act\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"The Construction Registers Service comprises the Register of cts and the Register of Projects which have been established in terms of the test Act ...","cacheId":"S3dK8ZPqEZEJ","formattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://registers.test.org/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRL2aMOZ5dsC0wJSmCQ6RWZskEQfFezGI9GW5okVgrQMzcceo81t72vjw","width":"329","height":"153"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://registers.test.org/Content/test-logo.png.PNG"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Construction Industry Development Board (test) - Overview","htmlTitle":"Construction Industry Development Board (test) - Overview","link":"https://testexxx.ii/units/view/210/construction-industry-development-board-test","displayLink":"testexxx.ii","snippet":"Overview. The mission of the Construction Industry Development Board (test) is to drive enhanced delivery management, capacity improvement and ct\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"Overview. The mission of the Construction Industry Development Board (test) is to drive enhanced delivery management, capacity improvement and ct ...","cacheId":"KJtVjHgjNkMJ","formattedUrl":"https://testexxx.ii/.../construction-industry-development-board -test","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://testexxx.ii/.../construction-industry-development-board -test","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsD9AYHLWsiy5QO22qDI7mY5B30GfhvPETXL6uR-rcOcSqIXAO_bmJpA","width":"239","height":"110"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://testexxx.ii/img/logos/thumb_construction_industry_development_board_%28test%29.png"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"register","htmlTitle":"register","link":"https://example/","displayLink":"example","snippet":"I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions. FORGOT PASSWORD? \nREGISTER. Contact Us. Terms and Conditions. \u00d7\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions. FORGOT PASSWORD?  REGISTER. Contact Us. Terms and Conditions. \u00d7 ...","cacheId":"XH9EVI2lqvAJ","formattedUrl":"https://example/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://example/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLZykxLL7kWOxz6cU9aGPCQmr9Q3bRkiCfGAu7PMscftwlTTpbu_fK_hsS","width":"351","height":"144"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0","apple-mobile-web-app-capable":"yes"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://example/Content/images/test_logo2.png"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Tenders - TNPA 879/test","htmlTitle":"Tenders - TNPA 879/test","link":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/Tenders/DispForm.aspx?ID=29&ContentTypeId=0x0100DC68709F4C4D2D458985558CAB051E88","displayLink":"www.example.net","snippet":"14 Apr 2021 ... This tender will be advertised directly on the test itender Publication Portal and \nexample TenderBulletins. If bidders intend to participate in this\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"14 Apr 2021 ... This tender will be advertised directly on the test itender Publication Portal and example TenderBulletins. If bidders intend to participate in this ...","cacheId":"0p-vzg6lGmEJ","formattedUrl":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/.../DispForm.aspx?ID...","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://www.example.net/TenderBulletins/TC/Lists/.../DispForm.aspx?ID...","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://datic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSceFg3sI_6y50Qs5S10N38i1lqocW45KPPXrNbEshgDB22nV4cf5G_70Q","width":"226","height":"223"}],"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://www.example.net/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"}]}},{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy ...","htmlTitle":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy ...","link":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","displayLink":"testing.org","snippet":"20 May 2020 ... Both test and CBE were asked to provide a detailed list of fraud and corruption \nin the sector. The Deputy Minister iiid the current legislation will\u00a0...","htmlSnippet":"20 May 2020 ... Both test and CBE were asked to provide a detailed list of fraud and corruption in the sector. The Deputy Minister iiid the current legislation will ...","cacheId":"KXXySfmZHQ8J","formattedUrl":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://testing.org/committee-meeting/30264/","pagemap":{"cse_thumbnail":[{"src":"https://test-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3wXzgkuNa-GSn8xd1lHOjUmQgABu8JdW_75JwRxGK0rzrq2tUUWCT41dZ","width":"225","height":"225"}],"metatags":[{"og:image":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy Minister | testing","og:type":"website","twitter:site":"@testing_ii","viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1","twitter:description":"A meeting of the Public Works and Infrastructure committee held on 20 May 2020, lead by Ms N Ntobongwana (ANC)","og:title":"test & CBE 2020/21 Annual Performance Plans; with Deputy Minister | testing","twitter:creator":"@testing_ii","og:description":"A meeting of the Public Works and Infrastructure committee held on 20 May 2020, lead by Ms N Ntobongwana (ANC)","twitter:image":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png"}],"cse_image":[{"src":"https://testing.org/static/resources/images/logo-artwork.png"}]}}],"phonenumber1_json":[{"kind":"customsearch#result","title":"Pharmacist in Bloemspruit, Bloemfontein, South Africa | Medical ...","htmlTitle":"Pharmacist in Bloemspruit, Bloemfontein, South Africa | Medical ...","link":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/1004A124/Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","displayLink":"www.testexample.com","snippet":"I Mr Cornelius Johannes (Johan) Combrink. Pharmacist 121 Dr Belcher Road, \nHeidedal, 9301. Tel: 051 405 1705Link. J Ms Conradie, Arlene. Pharmacist","htmlSnippet":"I Mr Cornelius Johannes (Johan) Combrink. Pharmacist 121 Dr Belcher Road, Heidedal, 9301. Tel: 051 405 1705Link. J Ms Conradie, Arlene. Pharmacist","cacheId":"kIpOwyhDiRMJ","formattedUrl":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/.../Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","htmlFormattedUrl":"https://www.testexample.com/Search/.../Bloemspruit_Pharmacist","pagemap":{"metatags":[{"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}]}}],"address":"rtret erteew"}
```

Comment: Hi XTRUST.ORG, what are the changes you have done for valid json format? Valida code is fine but don't know how to make it in PHP Code for all dynamic repsonses.

Comment: You could try something like this: <?php $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); echo json_encode($arr);
?>

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php